# Django select_related FK model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to list all the objects that are in Movie model that are Genre ForeignKey related say `comedy` genre list all Movie objects related to `comedy`

```
# models.py
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("genres:list", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)


# views.py
def genre_list(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Genre, slug=slug)
    movies = Movie.objects.select_related('genre').all()

    context = {
        "objects_list": movies,
    }
    return render(request, 'genres/genres_list.html', context)
```

template view `genres/genres_list.html`

```
{% for obj in objects_list %}
              <div class="box">
                  <b>{{ obj.title }}</b>
            </div>
{% endfor %}
```

nothing turns up what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"object_list"` shouldn't be `movies` and not `shows` like in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable name in the context, `object_list`, doesn't match the variable name in the template, `objects_list`.

```
context = {
    "object_list": shows,
}

{% for obj in objects_list %}
```

You need to use the same variable name in both places. I would recommend `object_list` because it is more common in Django, however something descriptive like `movies` would be even better.

Finally, if you want to select all the movies in a particular genre, then you should use `filter`.

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Genre, slug=slug)
movies = Movie.objects.filter(genre=instance)
```

You are currently using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related), which does something different.